# React children is a function: How to define TypeScript type correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a small React Component where the child is a function. I can't seem to figure out how to define the `children` prop in TypeScript.

```
class ClickOutside extends React.PureComponent<Props, {}> {
  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;

    return children({ setElementRef: this.setElementRef });
  }
}
```

I'm calling it this way:

```
<ClickOutside onOutsideClick={() => this.setState({ isOpen: false })}>
  {({ setElementRef }) => (
    <div ref={setElementRef}>
      {trigger}
      {children}
    </div>
  )}
</ClickOutside>
```

And this is what I tried to define the prop but it does not work at all. I have tried several other things but failed and I'm kinda lost here.

```
type Props = {
  children: ({ setElementRef: (el: HTMLElement) => any }) => React.ReactNode,
  onOutsideClick: Function,
}
```

EDIT:

This produces `';' expected.` on `=>`

When I change the type definition this way:

```
type Props = {
  children: ({ setElementRef: (el: HTMLElement) => any }),
  onOutsideClick: Function,
}
```

It produces this error:

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '{ setElementRef: (el: HTMLElement) => any; } | ({ setElementRef: (el: HTMLElement) => any; } & string) | ({ setElementRef: (el: HTMLElement) => any; } & number) | ({ setElementRef: (el: HTMLElement) => any; } & false) | ({ ...; } & true) | ({ ...; } & ReactElement<...>) | ({ ...; } & ReactNodeArray) | ({ ...; } & Re...' has no compatible call signatures.

Comment: What error you're getting in compilation?

Comment: Are you returning an array of ReactNodes maybe? I'd need to look at the ts error

Comment: @ShridharSharma I've edited my post - sorry

Comment: @FerSalas  I've edited my post - sorry

Comment: try to change `React.PureComponent` to `React.Component`

Answer (score 5):

You need to define the type of `setElementRef` in the de-structured object parameter of the `children` prop:

```
type Props = {
 children(options: { setElementRef(el: HTMLElement): any } ): React.ReactNode;
};
```

Remember that when de-structuring an object, the `:` symbol performs its JavaScript duties and reassigns a property name, whereas in this example you're expecting it to designate a type.